# How to get process list of running Linux VM using volatility?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

How to run volatility directly on RAM of a running VM, without need to get memory dump first?

Answer (score 1):

Volatility is not designed for analysis on live systems.

If you need to get VM's process list using a memory forensics framework and you're interested in live analysis of hypervisor, I suggest you to use Rekall:

[VM discovery and introspection with Rekall](http://www.rekall-forensic.com/posts/2014-10-03-vms.html#_live_analysis)